# Condition if list exists inside list

Tags: c#, json, linq, api, model-view-controller

I am coding an API method that returns JSON in the following format:

```
{  
   "Results":[  
      {  
         "Rooms":[  
            {  
               "Name":"Deluxe Room",
               "Adults":2,
               "Children":0
            },
            {  
               "Name":"Single Room",
               "Adults":1,
               "Children":0
            }
         ],
         "Options":[  
            {  
               "Name":"Room Only",
               "Price":"100" 
            },
            {  
               "Name":"Breakfast",
               "Price":"200" 
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I form this JSON from data where I get combinations of `Rooms` : Each 2 rooms together have only 1 option.

I want to check, if the combination of rooms (Name/Adult/Children) is already available, I only want to add the `option` to the existing `Options`.

Class:

```
public class Results
{
    public List<RoomList> Rooms { get; set; }
    public List<Option> Options { get; set; }
}
```

So what I want to do is: loop through `Results`, and inside each `Result` I want to check if the `RoomList` is already available in another `Result`: If it is available, I add the `Option` to list : `Options` . If It is new, I add a new item to `Results`.

I tried doing this:

```
//Fill roomOption

//Fill roomList

                            Results Results= new Results();
                            if (!Results.Exists(e => e.RoomList == roomList))
                            {
                               Results result = new Results()
                                {
                                    RoomList = roomList
                                };
                                //add the option
                                if (result.Options == null)
                                    result.Options = new List<Option>();
                                result.Options.Add(roomOption);
                                results.Add(result);
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                result= Results.Where(e => e.RoomList == roomList).FirstOrDefault();
                                //Add the option to the already existing room list
                                if (result.Options == null)
                                    result.Options = new List<Option>();
                                result.Options.Add(roomOption);

                            }
```

I need to replace the condition `Results.Exists(e => e.RoomList == roomList)` with something else.

Can anyone help

Comment: Trying to understand what you put, you said each two rooms together only have one option, but then have a list of two options for the two rooms. Could you clarify that part?

Comment: @Dispersia Im sorry what I meant is before I form this JSON, I receive an XML where each 2 rooms have 1 option. I need to do the algorithm that forms the JSON above where if these 2 rooms already exist, i dont add them again i just add 1 option to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Results is an IEnumerable of Result

**Option #1**

First you will want to override equals on the Room object like so

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var other = (Room) obj;
    return string.Equals(Name, other.Name) 
        && Adults == other.Adults 
        && Children == other.Children;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        var hashCode = Name.GetHashCode();
        hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Adults;
        hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Children;
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Then in your code you can very elegantly put

```
if (!Results.Any(e => e.Rooms.Count() == roomList.Count() 
     && e.Rooms.All(x => roomList.Contains(x))))
```

and also adjust "result = Results.Where(e => e.RoomList == roomList).FirstOrDefault()" to

```
result = Results.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Rooms.Count() == roomList.Count()
    && e.Rooms.All(x => roomList.Contains(x)));
```

Side note if you are concerned about nulls or comparing Room with other type of objects use this equals method instead

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
    if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
    return Equals((Room) obj);
}

protected bool Equals(Room other)
{
    return string.Equals(Name, other.Name) && Adults == other.Adults && Children == other.Children;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = Name.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Adults;
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Children;
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
```

**Option 2**

If you either don't want or can't override equals then you can make a method like this

```
private bool DoesRoomMatch(Room rm1, Room rm2)
{
    return string.Equals(rm1.Name, rm2.Name) 
        && rm1.Adults == rm2.Adults 
        && rm1.Children == rm2.Children;
}
```

Then the two statements become

```
if (!Results.Any(e => e.Rooms.Count() == roomList.Count() 
     && e.Rooms.All(x => roomList.Any(y => DoesRoomMatch(x, y)))))

result = Results.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Rooms.Count() == roomList.Count()
    && e.Rooms.All(x => roomList.Any(y => DoesRoomMatch(x, y))));
```

BTW You can use FirstOrDefault in place of a Where

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have to check if a room is already in the Results.

So you should loop over the roomList and for each element check if Results.Rooms.Contains(room).

Override the Equals method if is needed.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope it helps!

Comment: I want to check if the room *combination* is already available in the roomLists, not just one room